# Look for items from a list into a file and pull columns from those matching lines

Tags: python, list, file, pattern-matching

I have a list as follows:

```
 [abc,efg,dfg]
 [tac,thc,kfl]
 [etc,acy,qof]
```

and I want to pull out lines which have lines containing **all** of the values in the list in that line, for eg if I have a file

```
 EAF 123 abc 567 efg dfg
 TAC 234 tic 576 qud tic
 QAC 586 qwa 786 tov ypv
 CVB 078 abc efg dfg qtc
 TCB 398 tac thc kfl tqo
 OCN 068 etc acy qof qic
```

I get the lines containing the components of the list as :

```
 123 abc 567 efg dfg     
 398 tac thc kfl tqo
 068 etc acy qof qic
```

I am trying to use this code:

```
 textfile = open("file_checkin.txt",'rb')
  for lines in textfile.xreadlines():
   if any(value in lines for value in list):
    print lines.strip()
   else:
    continue
```

However is there an option that I can use to substitute **any** with something to include **all** the items in the list to match that line?

Comment: Use the `all` statement.   Another one: do you really need to use `else: continue` ? Can't you omit it?

Comment: This is shorter code: `pprint([lines.strip() for lines in textfile.xreadlines() if any(value in lines for value in list)])`. You need to `from pprint import pprint`.

Comment: hi @Elmex80s yes I can omit the else: and I tried implementing it , it did work thanks